# How do i access the id of a particular image contained in a div onclick using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Am new to jquery and i really need help.I have 4 divs each of which have 4 images in them.I have used toggle to show and hide the images.I need to reduce the size of my code and probably need to use "this".I tried to use it but dint work.Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var par = $("#11");
      $(par).hide();
        $("#one").click(function(e) {
          $(par).toggle();
          e.preventDefault();
      });
      var para = $("#12");
      $(para).hide();
        $("#two").click(function(e) {
          $(para).toggle();
          e.preventDefault();
      });
      var parb = $("#21");
      $(parb).hide();
        $("#three").click(function(e) {
          $(parb).toggle();
          e.preventDefault();
      });
      var parc = $("#22");
      $(parc).hide();
        $("#four").click(function(e) {
          $(parc).toggle();
          e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="outline">
     <div id="one">
         <a href="#"><img id="11" src="1.png"></a>
     </div>
     <div id="two">
         <img  id ="12" src="2.png">
     </div>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
     <div id="three">
         <img id="21" src="2.png">
     </div>
     <div id="four" >
         <img id="22" src="1.png">
     </div>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by selecting all `img` elements and `hide`-ing them. Then navigate up to the parent `div` and attach a `click` event listener which will toggle the contained `img` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.outline img').hide().closest('div').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('img',this).toggle();
    });
});
```

[**Concept Verification**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/q7g1c1zc/)

Answer (score 1):

Do You really need to distinguish every image? If not there's a simple solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.outline').find('img').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly You need to select every img in .outline div. Then For each of them You bind onClick event. I might be wrong, but think e.preventDefault() should be the first thing in onClick event (if You need to prevent the normal event).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do something. I also used a bit of CSS to help you, but it's not required.

I didn't understand if you need to distinguish the images in the div, so let me know if it's useful.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/evzc0n65/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".outline div").click(function() {
        $('img',this).toggle();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: may want to update the fiddle to your code vs the original :)

Comment: Thankyou so much this worked well too but needed the images to hide initially.